# how to concat all columns in a spark dataframe, using java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

This is how I do do for 2 specific columns:

```
dataSet.withColumn("colName", concat(dataSet.col("col1"), lit(","),dataSet.col("col2") ));
```

but `dataSet.columns()` retruns Sting array, and not Column array.
How should I craete a  `List<Column>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple Way** - Instead of `df.columns` use `concat_ws(",","*")`, Check below code.

```
df.withColumn("colName",expr("concat_ws(',',*)")).show(false)
+---+--------+---+-------------+
|id |name    |age|colName      |
+---+--------+---+-------------+
|1  |Srinivas|29 |1,Srinivas,29|
|2  |Ravi    |30 |2,Ravi,30    |
+---+--------+---+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has more verbose syntax.
Try this -

```java
 df.withColumn("colName",concat_ws(",", toScalaSeq(Arrays.stream(df.columns()).map(functions::col).collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Use below utility to convert java list to scala seq-

```java
  <T> Buffer<T> toScalaSeq(List<T> list) {
        return JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a way to concat all the columns of a DataFrame in Scala, this is what worked for me:

```
val df_new = df.withColumn(new_column_name, concat_ws("-", df.columns.map(col): _*))
```